# Normal attack (right mouse click) doesn't always work

Tags: pc, dark-souls-2

This problem occurs so many times in my PC version of dark soul 2: Sometimes when I right-click, it does not respond, and my character does not attack for 1-2 seconds. I did not set any action related to double right-click, and my mouse works perfectly outside of game or in game menu.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: When/How does this happen? What weapons have you equipped in each slot? Can you provide a bit more information regarding that.

Comment: Does your mouse function properly outside of the game?

Comment: @Samyam, it appeared several times throughout the game, and today when I was fighting those giant knight around Cathedral, my mouse clicked stopped working(only in combat, it's working in game menu or windows).

Comment: @slow_excellence, yes, the problem only occurs in game, specifically in combat, can use mouse clicking in game menu.

Comment: Can you confirm if it is not one of these - 1. You are running out of stamina while fighting.(The green bar at the top left). 2. You are not stunned due to enemy attacks.

Comment: Try binding whatever you currently have bound to right-click to another key on the keyboard and see if the same thing occurs that way. @Samyam's suggestion seems to be a likely possibility also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did not set any action related to double right-click

I think that your problem is this. For some reason FROM decided that it is a good idea to use double-click as an entirely different category instead of just chaining a click. This means they need to detect the double-click, which **persists even if you assign nothing to double-click**. This moment of intelligence also blocks us from properly executing jumping strong attack (forward + strong attack at the same time)

This means that if you assign double-click to nothing and spam a click - hoping that finally the game will obey the common sense - the game will see you as initiating a double-click, sees that you assign nothing to double-click, and promptly does exactly what you told it to do: do nothing. It's not what you want it to do, but it's what it interpreted what you told it to do

You may want to check if your mouse's right click fires off in rapid succession with only one click, it might be the reason.

By the way this is also the reason I pretty much use keyboard keys instead of mouse clicks for my attacks. I assign the right hand normal attack to C and right hand strong attack to E

Comment: Wow I've never heard of a game using double-right click as an action before. One more reason to recommend playing it with a controller eh

Comment: It certainly is idiotic. Perhaps they could have used a combination key (such as maybe in combination with shift) but noooo, they have to detect double-click, with means when you're panicking the software itself will turn against you

Comment: I think that's where the problem is, as what I wrote in answer section, the way to solve this is use third party tool to bind mouse click to the keyboard key, it's kind of inconvenient but works pretty well.

Comment: Never tried AHK before, maybe I'll give it a spin. Didn't see that one before

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if this is only in a new version, but you can also disable the "Double Click" option under "Key Bindings" -> "Mouse" -> Set "Disable Double Clicking" to "On". Then the double click does not result in a "No Action" if you have it not hotkeyed to anything, like I had. Drove me crazy for the last 30 Minutes o.O

Comment: The worst part about this setting is that it RESETS. You have to set it to OFF and then back ON every time you restart the game. If you right click and you do not immediately block or attack (delay is about 250ms), then you need to set to OFF, confirm, set back to ON (for disabled). This happens for both the original and SOTFS version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what is causing this, but I've found a way to get rid of all the delayed performance, and sometimes no response from mouse.
Basically you use hotkey app to bind mouse click to attack keys on keyboard, which works perfectly and has no delay to wait mouse double clicking.
Here is the detailed solution for this problem:http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/23zq0s/mousekeyboard_fix/